# Parsing input with variable multiple indentifier blocks and different semantics at start of string without lookbehind

Tags: javascript, regex

I wrote [some regex](https://github.com/SamHH/bukubrow/blob/16c9fb50dc83b3ae627115b34278dcfd37096272/webextension/src/modules/parse-search-input.ts#L2-L4) that could look at a string and pluck out a variable number of matches. These matches are determined with a special starting string, however it's a little different if they're at the start of the string, and they also shouldn't be collected in the result. (Forgive my lack of proper regex terminology!) It's probably not very well written, but it mostly works. The problem is that it uses lookbehind, and this still isn't supported by Firefox. As such, I'd love some help in refactoring it. Here's an example:

```
 /(?<=(?:^| +)#).+?(?:(?= +[#>:].+)|$)/g
```

Some inputs and expected outputs:

`hello #a tag here #another tag :something else #tags` -> `['a tag here', 'another tag', 'tags']`

`#tag` -> `['tag']`

`#x #` (space at start of string, SO is removing it for some reason) -> `['x']`

`#x #y` -> `['x', 'y']`

`#x#y` -> `['x#y']`

Cheers!

Comment: The required contents can be captured from Group 1 of each match [`#([\w#]+[^#:\r\n]*)(?=\s+|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/jf312Z/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may capture the substrings you need:

```
/(?:^| )#(.+?)(?= +[#>:]|$)/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WiY8Yi/1). To match any whitespace chars, replace the regular spaces in the pattern with `\s`.

**Details**

- `(?:^| )` - start of string or space
- `#` - a `#` char
- `(.+?)` - any 1 or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?= +[#>:]|$)` - there must be end of string at this location, or 1+ spaces followed with `#`, `>` or  `:`.

```js
var strs = ['hello #a tag here #another tag :something else #tags','#tag','#x #y','#x#y',' #x'];
for (var s of strs) {
  var rx = /(?:^| )#(.+?)(?= +[#>:]|$)/g;
  console.log(s);
  var m, res = [];  
  while (m=rx.exec(s)) {
    res.push(m[1]);
  }
  console.log(res);
}
```

Comment: ```
const input = 'thing >desc #tag1 #tag2 :url';
const r = /(?:^| )#(.+?)(?= +[#>:]|$)/g;

input.match(r); // [' #ŧag1', ' #tag2']
```

Is this producing a different result due to your using exec versus my match?

Comment: @SamHH Do not use `match` with `g`-based regex as all captured substrings will be lost. Use my solution.